# What are the conditions for a pod to be treated as failed

Tags: kubernetes, openshift

I am aware of how replicaset works and how it will reconcile the state from its specification .

However, I am not completely aware of what are all the criteria Replicaset uses for it it to reconcile the state ?

I happened to take look the documentation to understand the scenarios.
https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/replicaset/

1. One scenarios is when the pod is down for any reason - application issue
2. Node is down

What are all the other scenarios ? If the pod is stuck in making progress, will replica set take care of that ? Or is it just check whether the pod is alive or not ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If the pod is stuck in making progress, will replica set take care of that ?

As long as the main process inside of a container is running, it is considered healthy by default and it will be treated as such. If there is an application issue which prevents your application from working correctly but the main process is still running, you will be stuck with an "unhealthy" pod.

That is the reason why you want to implement `livenessProbe` for your containers and specify what "behavior" represents a healthy state of the container. In such scenario, failure to successfully respond to health check multiple times (configurable) will result in a container being treated as failed and your replica set will take an action.

Example might be a simple HTTP GET request to some predefined path if you are running web application in your pod (eg `/api/health`). Now, even if main process is running, your application needs to periodically respond to this health-check query otherwise it will be replaced.

Comment: so, it is as good as saying Replicaset will create the pod only it is down or node is down ? Rest of the scenarios need to be take care by developer to give  hints to the  kubernetes to kill the pod ( like using Probes ?

Comment: basically yes. You should not rely on the default behavior and always define liveness probe.

Answer (score 0):

1. OOM Killed issue - which cause pod kill and restart pod
2. Cpu limit issue - This cause 404 issue but do not restart pod

Comment: Is there any link that points to certain criteria or it is just guess based on the error type - recoverable or not recoverable

Comment: @Nag I faced these error on day to day life and my personal experiences. You can search on google and you will find out a lot of question on these.

Comment: For OOM and CPU limit issue there is one solution HPA (Horizontal pod autosacler) in kubernetes

Comment: I am aware of these scenarios in general, but looking for a specific answer. Thanks.anyway

Answer (score 0):

If the Pod or the Node is not down, the Pod will only fail and a new one will be created if you have Liveness Probe defined.

If you don't have it implemented, k8s will never know that your Pod is not up and running.

Take a look at [this doc page](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-startup-probes/) for more info.

Comment: so, it is as good as saying Replicaset will create the pod only it is down or node is down ? Rest of the scenarios need to be take care by developer to give  hints to the  kubernetes to kill the pod ( like using Probes ?

Comment: answered by @Matus above ;)